# Finding electric field outside solid sphere of uniform charge (treated as many discs of charge)

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, symmetry, gauss-law, coulombs-law

All of the methods on finding an electric field outside a solid sphere of charge use Gauss's Law. However, is it possible to derive the electric field by treating the solid sphere as combined infinitesimally thin discs of charge?

Comment: Instead of thinking about disks, I think it advantageous to consider the whole dv volume element as one single entity, and then use spherical coordinates to evaluate the integral, without the use of gauss law.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can first compute the electric field outside a spherical *shell* by considering the shell to be made up of circular *rings* that are perpendicular to the line between the field point and the sphere’s center. All points on such a ring are equidistant from the field point, so the ring’s contribution is trivial. The details of that calculation can be found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem#Outside_a_shell).

Then you can compute the field outside a solid sphere by considering it to be made up of spherical shells.

Comment: That's not what OP is asking, though - he wants disks, not rings.

Comment: ...from rings to disks...from disks to solid sphere (ball).

Comment: @Frobenius That's not at all guaranteed to work in practice. The electric field of a disk can be hellish to calculate explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that as follows. Let $R$ be the radius of the sphere and $\rho = \frac{Q}{\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3}$ the volume charge density ($Q$ is the total charge on the sphere). Now consider a disk of radius $r$ at a distance $x$ from the center of the sphere, and notice that $x^2 + r^2 = R^2$ according to Pithagorean theorem. Now the infinitesimal electric field induced by the disk on a point $P$ at distance $x_P$ from the center of the sphere and hence $x_P - x$ from the center of the disk is
$$
dE_x = \frac{\rho dx}{2\varepsilon_0} \left(1 - \frac{x_P-x}{\sqrt{r^2 + (x_P-x)^2}} \right),
$$
where notice that $\rho dx$ is the surface charge density on the specific disk and I am assuming $x_P>x$ (fine for a point out of the sphere). I start from this result, but this can be checked by dividing the disk in many concentrical rings, as others pointed out.
Now let us use $r^2 = R^2-x^2$ to have a single independent variable $x$ in our expression, and let us also substitute $\xi = x/R$, $a=x_P/R$:
$$
dE_x = \frac{\rho Rd\xi}{2\varepsilon_0} \left( 1 - \frac{a - \xi}{\sqrt{1+a^2-2a\xi}} \right).
$$
At this point we need to sum all the contributions coming from all the disks labeled by their distance from the center $x$, which ranges from $-R$ to $R$, or equivalently by $\xi$, which ranges from $-1$ to $1$:
$$
E_x = \frac{\rho R}{2\varepsilon_0} \int_{-1}^1 d\xi \left(1 - \frac{a-\xi}{\sqrt{1+a^2-2a\xi}} \right)
$$
Now let me skip the details of this integration, which is lengthy but straightforward, and the final result is
$$
\int_{-1}^1 d\xi \left(1 - \frac{a-\xi}{\sqrt{1+a^2-2a\xi}} \right) = 
\frac{2}{3a^2} \,\,\,\, \text{if} \,\,\, a \geq 1 
$$
Now if you substitute back $a=x_P/R$ and you simplify a little bit you get the usual result that you find with Gauss law, i.e.:
$$
E = \frac{Q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 x_P^2} \,\,\,\, \text{if} \,\,\, x_P \geq R
$$

**Edit**

For completeness let me also add what happens if $P$ is inside the sphere.
In this situation the assumption $x_P>x$ doesn't necessarily hold. In fact now there are disks with $x<x_P$ and disks with $x>x_P$, thus we need to generalize the equation of the electric field produced by a disk:
$$
dE_x = \frac{\rho R}{2\varepsilon_0} d\xi \left(1 - \frac{a-\xi}{\sqrt{1+a^2-2a\xi}} \right) \,\,\,\, \text{if} \,\,\, \xi < a
$$
$$
dE_x = -\frac{\rho R}{2\varepsilon_0} d\xi \left(1 - \frac{\xi-a}{\sqrt{1+a^2-2a\xi}} \right) \,\,\,\, \text{if} \,\,\, \xi > a
$$
Now when you integrate all the contributions, you get
$$
E_x = \frac{\rho R}{2\varepsilon_0} \left[ \int_{-1}^a d\xi \left(1 - \frac{a-\xi}{\sqrt{1+a^2-2a\xi}} \right) -  \int_{a}^1 d\xi \left(1 - \frac{\xi - a}{\sqrt{1+a^2-2a\xi}} \right) \right]
$$
which after lengthier calculations results
$$
E_x = \frac{\rho R}{2\varepsilon_0} \frac{2a}{3} = \frac{\rho x_P}{3\varepsilon_0},
$$
which is the correct result for the fild inside the sphere.